# Storing Excel file using Binary content issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

- Laravel Version: 5.5
- PHP Version `$ php --version`: PHP PHP 7.1.3 (cli)
- Database Driver & Version $ `mysql --version`: mysql  Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

---

#### Problem Statement:

We are storing files on an S3 bucket and want to load them via `load` method.

> Could not open storage/app/path/file.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.

---

#### Files and Configuration:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007;


      $path = Storage::disk('s3-storage')->path('app/path/' , $filename);

      $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
      $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
      $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($path);
```

`config/filesystems.php`

```
        's3-storage' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'root' => '/storage',
        ],
```

---

```
Storage::disk('s3-storage')->get()
```

The `get` method return raw string contents.

Which will throw Error on **PHPExcel** `load` method.

---

### Edit 1:

After storing XLSX file using Laravel Storage `put()` method. It is writing all the **binary** content in first row of file.

[image]

Comment: What if you use `file_get_contents` on S3 file ($path) and save its binary as an xls or xlsx file use `file_put_contents`, get the file path and then load it use PHPExcel?

Comment: @AuliaWiguna Can you show implementation of it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//get the path
$path = Storage::disk('s3-storage')->url($filename);
//read the content
$contents = file_get_contents($path);
//put content
Storage::disk('local')->put('file.xls', $contents);
// then it would store a file in storage/app/file.xls.

$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load(storage_path('app/file.xls'));
```